# Redirect application with fixed path with nginx

Tags: nginx

My server is behind a reverse proxy of our university. I got the domain myuniverse.org/mysubdomain/.

Unfortunately the application I want to use always changes the path: myuniverse.org/mysubdomain/ automatically becomes myuniverse.org/myappname/ and this domain is not accessible.
If I access my server via IP from the university network everything is fine, because myIP/myappname works.

Is there a way to redirect this behavior with nginx?

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name myServerName;


        location / {
        proxy_pass http://10.11.0.3:8080;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to make your application think that it is on a path it is actually not. This can be done by rewriting destination at `proxy_pass`:

```
  location ~ ^/mysubdomain(/.*)?$ {
    proxy_pass http://10.11.0.3:8080/myappname$1$is_args$args;
    # this example does not include proxy_set_header for simplicity but you may need it
  }
```

However, I would not recommend you do that in most cases. The above will help you to get a response to the initial request, but because your application will think it is on a different path, consequent requests (to static files or sub-pages) may be broken if a link will contain `/myappname` in it. NGINX can rewrite URLs in proxied responses but it is another hack with its own downsides.

What you really need is to change the base URI of the application from `/myappname` to `/mysubdomain`. This will make it work with no hacks involved.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I managed to change the URI as you suggested.